# The parallelism of a stream is always that of its producing operator

Tags: apache-flink

In https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows, there is a description

> The number of operator subtasks is the parallelism of that particular
>   operator. The parallelism of a stream is always that of its producing
>   operator. Different operators of the same program may have different
>   levels of parallelism.

I don't understand what `The parallelism of a stream is always that of its producing operator.` means, could someone please help explain more? Thanks！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement isn't saying anything profound, imo. Operators produce streams. Operators have one or more parallel instances, sometimes referred to as subtasks, each of which is producing a portion of the stream.